# How do I reset a screens state to its initial state when using react navigation?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

I want to reset the state (back to initial state) in a functional component when navigated via `navigation.navigate()`.

Say a user navigates to an `A` screen and some state is set, then they click a button on that screen and navigate to a `B` screen via `navigation.navigate('B`);`

The problem Im having appears when the user clicks another button to go back to the `A` screen (again via `navigation.navigate('A');`). The `A` component at this point is still holding all the state from its initial mount. I want the state to be reset to the initial state for the `A` component so users have to start whatever process over again from the beginning.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I attempted some half measure of listening for that navigation back and resetting the state with a bunch of `set` hooks, but it feels wrong and does not work very well.

Edit:
Someone asked for a code sample, so a quick example is below. The problem is; if someone navigates to component `A` and clicks the button that calls `setInput` which makes text appear above the buttons, they then click the other button labeled `Go To B` which react navigation takes them to component `B`. If they then proceed and click `Go To A` and are then navigated back to component `A`, component `A` will still have the `input` state equal to `Hello`. I want it to be reset back to an empty string (hopefully without having to call `setInput("")`.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {Center, Button, Text} from "native-base";

const A = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  return (
    <Center>
      <Text>{input}</Text>
      <Button onPress=(() => { setInput("Hello") })>Click Me For Words</Button>
      <Button onPress=(() => { navigation.navigate("B") })>Go To B</Button>
    </Center>
  );
};

const B = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  return (
    <Center>
      <Button onPress=(() => { navigation.navigate("A") })>Go To A</Button>
    </Center>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you show the code ?

Comment: Please share the code snippet to understand better. 

You have a prop called `isFocused` that comes from navigation. Check for it and update your state when your screen gets unfocused.

Comment: @ImanpalSingh I have included an example now, sorry for not including that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question. Basically if you want to unmount/remount the component (which will reset its state) you can do:

```js
const resetAction = CommonActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  routes: [{ name: "A" }]
});
navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

Comment: where do you do this?

Comment: am wondering the same thing

Answer (score 12):

You can try this, it will set `setInput("")` when you come back to `screen A`  from `screen B`

```
useEffect(() => {
   const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
         setInput("");
   });
   return unsubscribe;
}, [navigation]);
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {Center, Button, Text} from "native-base";

const A = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
     const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
         setInput("");
     });
     return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  return (
    <Center>
      <Text>{input}</Text>
      <Button onPress=(() => { setInput("Hello") })>Click Me For 
      Words</Button>
      <Button onPress=(() => { navigation.navigate("B") })>Go To B</Button>
    </Center>
  );
};

const B = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  return (
    <Center>
      <Button onPress=(() => { navigation.navigate("A") })>Go To A</Button>
    </Center>
  );
};
```

Comment: When are you calling the unsubscribe?

Comment: @LeonardoRick - React calls the returned function from `useEffect` hooks upon unmounting

Comment: Did not work for this

const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
        setEmail('');
        setName(''); 
    });
    return unsubscribe;
 }, [navigation]);

Answer (score 7):

```
  <Drawer.Screen
    name="Your Screen"
    component={screen.ConcernAddScreen}
    options={{unmountOnBlur: true}} // This right here will mount the component and reset your screen
  />
```

Comment: This is what I've been looking for! Many thanks, Hashir!

Comment: This only works for Drawer and BottomTab navigators, though. Stack navigators don't have the `unmountOnBlur` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the React Native life cycle method like as:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    console.log('onResume')
    //call your method here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

React Navigation unfortunately doesn't unmount the component when changing screens for some ungodly reason. If you want to get back to default React behaviour you can use this snippet anywhere you would use `useState`.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useCustomState = (navigation: any, defaultValue: any) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue);

    useEffect(() => {
        return navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
            setValue(defaultValue);
        });
    }, [navigation]);

    return [value, setValue];
};
```

And using it like so

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useCustomState(navigation, 0);
```

Comment: and if you are using useNavigate, there is no "navigation" what would you use instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by creating a listener for the navigation focus event (`return navigation.addListener("focus", () => {})`) and adding it to the unmount method of the component.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

export const useCustomState = (navigation) => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        return navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
            setUsername(defaultValue);
        });
    }, [navigation]);

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{username}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```